# Run four tasks with a preset schedule in C#

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have an exercise in asynchronous programming like this:
There are 4 Tasks: `Task1`, `Task2`, `Task3`, `Task4`.
`Task1` and `Task2` run in parallel. `Task3` is only run when either `Task1` or `Task2` completes. `Task4` runs when all 3 previous tasks must be completed.
This is how I do it, but my teacher asked me not to separate the function to handle `Task.WaitAny()` (in the picture is the `waitAny()` function), and not to use async in `ContinueWith`.
Can someone help me?
[Screenshot with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9ujC.png).

```
static async Task<int> waitAny()
{
    return Task.WaitAny(runTask1(), runTask2());
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    waitAny().ContinueWith( 
    async (_taskToContinue) => 
    {
        await runTask3();

        Task.WaitAll(runTask1(), runTask2(), runTask3());

        await runTask4();

    });

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Please add the code as a text.

Comment: here is the code as text, sorry this is my first time posting a question on stackoverflow

Comment: By tasks `Task1`, `Task2`, `Task3` and `Task4`, do you mean the asynchronous functions `runTask1`, `runTask2`, `runTask3` and `runTask4`?

Comment: Yes, it's a function to run my task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would do it like this then.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task1 = runTask1();
        var task2 = runTask2();

        Task.WhenAny(task1, task2).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            var task3 = runTask3();

            Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);

            var task4 = runTask4();
            task4.Wait();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I need. Thank you very much, have a good day <3

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this as answere then with the green hook :).